# Yaml Compile Variables are not working while passing parameter from runtime in azure Devops

Tags: azure, yaml, devops

We have runtime input from csv file to Yaml and we are able to read and pass the variable to other stages and job. when we pass the parameter to another Yaml file and we are not able to read the compile time variables
below the code

i have issue with enabled: ${{ eq(parameters.deployKvl1, 'true') }} , when I am passing true and its not taking correct value and always false in compile time
`${{ eq(parameters.deployKvl1, 'true') }}`  -- this code is not working

depoly.yml

```
stages:
  - stage: StaticTesting
    displayName: 'Static Testing'
    jobs:
      - job: staticTesting
        displayName: 'Static (Unit)  '
        continueOnError: false 
        pool:
          vmImage: 'windows-latest'
        steps:

        - task: PowerShell@2
          inputs:
             targetType: 'filePath'
             filePath: NewDeployment/Get-CSV.ps1
             arguments: > 
          name: GETCSV
       
        - powershell: |
              
              Echo $(GETCSV.PdeployKvl1)
                                
  - stage: Dev
    dependsOn: StaticTesting
    displayName: 'Dev Deployment'
    condition: and(succeeded(), in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual', 'IndividualCI', 'BatchedCI'))
    variables:
        # map the output variable from A into this job
         deployKvl1: $[ stageDependencies.StaticTesting.staticTesting.outputs['GETCSV.PdeployKvl1'] ]
        
    

    jobs:
   
     - template: Env.yml
       parameters:
            #common Params
             pool: '${{ variables.devpool }}'
              keyVaultName1: $(NKV)
             deployKvl1:  $(deployKvl1)
             #keyvault Params Ingestion kvl
```

Env.yml

```
parameters:
#common params

  - name: keyVaultName1
    type: string
  - name: deployKvl1
    type: string

jobs:
   
    
    - job: KVLValidation
      displayName: 'Validation of Key Vault'
      continueOnError: false
      pool: ${{ parameters.pool }}

       
        - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
          name: keyn
          displayName: Deploy key 
          enabled: ${{ eq(parameters.deployKvl1, 'true') }} 
          continueOnError: false
          inputs:
            deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
           ..........
           .........
```

Comment: „*this code is not working*“ is not an error description. Please describe the expected behavior and the actual behavior. `arguments: >` looks wrong since no folded block scalar follows.

Comment: i have issue with enabled: ${{ eq(parameters.deployKvl1, 'true') }}  , when I am passing true and its not taking correct value and always false in compile time